# what is the format of message that we pass to MSPN service?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

What is the format of message that we pass to MSPN service from our cloud application in the case of push notification in windows 7 phone? I know its XML but what all information should it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN article on [Sending Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) includes all details and examples of the different Push notification content types.

There's also more on Push Notifications at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537(v=vs.92).aspx